# Your helper image isn't very helpful

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, design

On documentation, there seems to be some fudged up razor tag somewhere thats messing up an image.

[image: this]

Comment: 100% repro.  Any topic will show this.

Answer (score 3):

The `SvgHelper` was being used there in a way that it wasn't designed for and a recent change to the class caused this issue.

Nick fixed the helper to support this scenario and the fix has since been deployed.

Thanks for reporting!